# delete node in a xml file with sed

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to delete a node from my flatten xml file, my xml file contains following:

```
...
<cellule ref="1111"/>
</blah>
<workdocument id="bar" classement="1"/>
<tablau id="35">
<cellule ref="1250"/>
<area id="foo">
<subarea>Ipsum Lorem Dolor</subarea>
<area>
...
```

I need to remove `<workdocument id="bar" classement="1"/>`, so from element `<workdocument` until it is closing "`/>`"

I tried the following with sed:

```
echo '<cellule ref="1111"/></blah><workdocument id="bar" classement="1"/><tablau id="35"><cellule ref="1250"/><area id="foo"><subarea>Ipsum Lorem Dolor</subarea><area>' |sed  's/<workdocument.*\/>//'
<cellule ref="1111"/></blah><area id="foo"><subarea>Ipsum Lorem Dolor</subarea><area>
```

but `<cellule ref="1250"/><area id="foo">` is also removed :/

Please note that the value of attribute classement is not known :/

Thank you

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to handle XML (or other structured data) with sed or similar tools. Is your input still valid XML? You might want to look into XML-handling tools such as xmlstarlet. In this case: `xmlstarlet ed -d //workdocument file.xml`

Comment: hi and thanks, yes it still valid, why I'm trying  to use sed instead is because I will use it in a bash script, and I'm not sure xmlstarlet is installed in all machines.

Comment: Bundle it, that's my suggestion. Or depend on something like python, which is ubiquitous and has XML-handling in its standard library. The problem with handling XML with sed is that suddenly it's not enough that your input is valid XML, it has to be XML that's formatted in a way your script can handle. For example, if I put a couple of newlines after `<workdocument` and before `id="bar"`, the input will still be perfectly valid XML but confuse your sed script. Think of comments, where anything can be written. No matter how you slice it, doing this with sed will be incredibly brittle.

Comment: nice thoughts, but since it is  the only operation I'll apply on the file, I want to choose a simple way to do it. maybe when i'll have more operations to do with i'll choose appropriate technique. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: `sed 's/<workdocument[^\/]*\/>//'`

This uses `[^/]*` instead of `.*` after `workdocument` so that its match doesn't exceed the first `/>`. `[^/]` matches every character other than `/`.

Comment: It works fine thank you, could you please give some explanations of the syntax used ?